# method is not being called by application

Tags: c#, winforms, azure, datagridview

My method is not being called by my application. I've used breakpoints and it's never initiated in the code. I'm building a C# Windows Forms application using an Azure Database, but the DataGridView is never being filled neither is the code being called at all... I have noooo clue whatsoever why..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace MyWinFormsProj
{
   public partial class CompanyForm : Form
{
    public CompanyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //Connection String
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    ["MyConnetion"].ConnectionString;

    // Load all employees
    private void dataEmployees_Load()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
            (
                "Select fname,ename FROM dbo.Users", con
            );
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dataEmployees.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }

    // Crate company
    private void createCompany_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBoxCompanyName.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fill out information");
            return;
        }
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            //Create SqlConnection
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "insert into dbo.Company  (companyName) 
             values(@companyName)", con);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@companyName", textBoxCompanyName.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            MessageBox.Show("Grattis! Du har skapat ett företag");

           }
        }
      }
    }
```

The second method is working and is doing what it is supposed to do, but the first one is never called..

Comment: Your code doesn't include a call to that method.

Comment: Where did you call that method? Maybe put a call in the constructor?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where the method is being called. Is the method dataEmployees_Load attached to any events on the form? If so check the code within InitializeComponent() to be sure it's correct.

Comment: @JoshuaHysong No it's just put on the form as a gridview and the I've applied the code behind it that is specified in the description of the problem. What kind of events could I attach to? Like onform load?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set an event handler on the gridView onLoad and pass this method to the handler

```
public void GridView_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataEmployees_Load();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your method signature to look like this:

```
private void dataEmployees_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Then, in your GirdView, you need to set this function as handler for event "onload":

```
OnLoad="dataEmployees_Load"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your answers it helped my solve the problem. Like you were saying the problem was in the method not being called. So I called it directly on initiliazeComponent like this.

```
    public partial class CompanyForm : Form
{
    public CompanyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += new EventHandler(dataEmployees_Load); //Added this code
    }
    // Load all employees
    private void dataEmployees_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
            (
                "Select fname,ename FROM dbo.Users", con
            );
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dataEmployees.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good that answers helped. Anyways, im more used to add the event handler in the aspx instead of in the code behind :)
Regards!